# How can I use a large wxCursor?

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

The [wx.Cursor](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxcursor.html) class automatically scales the image I give it to 32x32 and I need to use a cursor that is larger than that.

On http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307213 I saw what might be the reason for this behavior

> Although cursors can, in theory, be
>   any size, the system imposes a
>   standard size that is  exposed by
>   means of the SM_CXCURSOR and
>   SM_CYCURSOR values. These metrics are
>   read-only. On standard, low-DPI
>   systems, these metrics are set to
>   32x32 pixels (32 bytes/row). When the
>   system loads cursors by means of the
>   standard LoadCursor function, the
>   cursor is stretched to this dimension.

but I also saw that it can be done

> The system also provides the
>   SetSystemCursor API function that you
>   can use to change the system cursor
>   for specific categories. You can use
>   this function to set a cursor of any
>   size. However, you must call the
>   function programmatically, and you can
>   only use it to set a cursor for a
>   specific category. You cannot use it
>   to make all cursors on the system the
>   same size.

Is there something I am missing in the wx docs or must I directly call the windows api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out wx doesn't do anything to support non standard sized cursors.

http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-users/browse_thread/thread/326aea0d740b85dd/277483ad5df77539